# Docker build does not see existing bash script and can't run it

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker container for a tool named DECoN (versin 2.0.0). To do so, I'm doing these steps:

1. start `FROM` the latest bash image
2. `RUN` the download of the tool's source code and extract it
3. set the `WORKDIR` to the tool's `./Linux` subdirectory
4. `RUN` the *existing* `setup.sh` script that is found within the Linux subdirectory.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# start from a bash image 
FROM bash:latest

# download files 
RUN wget https://github.com/RahmanTeam/DECoN/archive/refs/tags/v2.0.0.tar.gz && \
    tar -xf v2.0.0.tar.gz

# go to directory 
WORKDIR DECoN-2.0.0/Linux

# run setup script 
RUN setup.sh

# check directory content 
RUN ls
```

You can see the existence of the script with the last `RUN ls`. However, the script is not found and the docker build returns the following error:

```
docker build -t decon:2.0.0 .

...

/bin/sh: setup.sh: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c setup.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I don't understand why the script is not found. I have tried `setup.sh`, `./setup.sh`, `/DECoN-2.0.0/Linux/setup.sh`, but nothing works.

EDIT #1: This is the content of the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

Rscript sessionInfo.R > setup.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this kind of problems, run the base image and execute the commands of the `Dockerfile` by hand on the prompt:

```
docker run -it --rm bash:latest
wget https://github.com/RahmanTeam/DECoN/archive/refs/tags/v2.0.0.tar.gz
tar -xf v2.0.0.tar.gz
cd DECoN-2.0.0/Linux
./setup.sh
```

The last line fails because, as you have noted, it runs `Rscript` which is not present in your (very minimal) base image.  `Rscript` belongs to the R language so I have tried again with the [official R base image](https://hub.docker.com/_/r-base):

```
docker run -it --rm r-base:latest bash
wget https://github.com/RahmanTeam/DECoN/archive/refs/tags/v2.0.0.tar.gz
tar -xf v2.0.0.tar.gz
cd DECoN-2.0.0/Linux
./setup.sh
```

This time the script runs and creates the following `setup.log`:

```
# Bootstrapping renv 0.15.4 --------------------------------------------------
* Downloading renv 0.15.4 ... OK
* Installing renv 0.15.4 ... Done!
* Successfully installed and loaded renv 0.15.4.
Error: package 'BiocManager' is not available
In addition: Warning messages:
1: This project is configured to use R version '4.2.0', but '4.3.1' is currently being used.
2: could not retrieve available packages for url 'https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/src/contrib'
Traceback (most recent calls last):
20: source("renv/activate.R")
19: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
18: eval(ei, envir)
17: eval(ei, envir)
16: local(...)
15: eval.parent(substitute(eval(quote(expr), envir)))
14: eval(expr, p)
13: eval(expr, p)
12: eval(quote(...), new.env())
11: eval(quote(...), new.env())
10: renv::load()
 9: renv_load_bioconductor(project, lockfile$Bioconductor)
 8: renv_bioconductor_init()
 7: renv_bioconductor_init_biocmanager()
 6: install("BiocManager")
 5: retrieve(names(remotes))
 4: handler(package, renv_retrieve_impl(package))
 3: renv_retrieve_impl(package)
 2: stopf("package '%s' is not available", package)
 1: stop(sprintf(fmt, ...), call. = call.)
Execution halted
```

The warning about the wrong version of R can be avoided by using `r-base:4.2.0` instead of `r-base:latest` (recommended to be safe) but the error message `package 'BiocManager' is not available` persists.

The URL referenced in the log is still valid and `BiocManager` is a package that must be installed within R.  Since I'm not an expert of R, I stop my analysis here hoping it helps.

**UPDATE:** Searching in Docker Hub I found some ready-made images that reference `RahmanTeam/DECoN` in the `Dockerfile`:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/stefpiatek/decon
- https://hub.docker.com/r/nderoo324/decon/tags

This one explictly installs `BiocManager`:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/euformatics/decon/tags

Other images could exist.

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful. It definitely made me reach a further point in the debugging, and I think I can take it from here. The docker hub images were my first attempt, but they reference an older version of the tool as far as I know. Thanks anyway for looking there too, really!

Comment: I'm very glad it helped. If you complete your work you could publish the resulting image on Docker Hub and add a link to it in a comment here for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

1. `RUN ./setup.sh` is the correct way to run a shell script in the current WORKDIR. You can only use `RUN setup.sh` if the script is on the path.
2. `ls -al` will confirm if the file has r-x permissions for the appropriate users. otherwise you will need to `RUN chmod +x setup.sh` to ensure it can be executed.
3. As you are using `bash:latest` is it unlikely that the script references a shell that is not present, but if the first line of the .sh file references a shell that's not present, it will return an error. i.e. If its `#!/bin/ash` then ensure that `ash` is actually present.
4. Again, as you are downloading and unzipping in the container, this is unlikely, but if the zip file has been processed on a windows computer, there may be CRLF line endings in the .sh file. As Linux only recognises LF this means it processes `#!/bin/bash<CR><LF>` as an instruction to execute the shell `/bin/bash<CR>` which does not exist. Download the file and check it in an editor (VSCode) that can tell you the ending style.

Comment: I've edited the main post with the content of the bash script. It seems ok, without special characters.

Comment: Running `file` returns `setup.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable`